использование LibreHardwareMonitorLib для управления работой кулерами
Я пишу программу для мониторинга и управления работой кулерами на C# MAUI.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно изменять скорость вращения кулеров ноутбука с использованием этой библиотеки? Нигде не смог найти информации про это, и в самой библиотеке не нашел свойства FanControl
Заранее спасибо!

Система питания и охлаждения в ноутбуках обычно полностью автоматизирована и управляется только через ПО вендора грубыми настройками типа "шумно", "нормально", "тихо". На всех ноутбуках по-разному. Ручное управление может быть недоступно, так как это просто может сжечь ноутбук.

ну должна же быть поддержка для управления кулерами в C#? мне бы хоть как-то попытаться взаимодействовать с ними)
